# Error in Using readPNG to read an edited png file created by Magick

Tags: r, png, rmagick

I'm trying to use `readPNG` to read a [png](/questions/tagged/png) file I created after using the [magick](/questions/tagged/magick) package. This is a png file I combined from two images using the Magick package. I need to use readPNG to read it as a raster file so that I can later insert it into a map using annotate_custom. But I got an error message saying:

> file is not in PNG format

```
A <- image_read("Alogo.jpg")
image_trim(A)
A_twick<-image_resize(A, "130x130")
print(A_twick)

B <- image_read("Blogo.jpg")
image_trim(B)

combined<-image_append(c(B,A))
print(combined)
image_write(combined, "combinedlogo.png")

logo <- readPNG("logo/combinedlogo.png")
# here is the error message "Error in readPNG("logo/combinedlogo.png") : file is not in PNG format"
```

`RI2<-RI+
        annotation_custom(combined, xmin=-71.92, xmax=-71.82, ymin=41.15, ymax=41.23)`

Did I miss anything? Or is there any workaround I could do to achieve my goal? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assumed Magick knew you wanted to save your file as a png because you used a ".png" file extension, but you actually need to specify it:

```r
magick::image_write(combined, "combinedlogo.png", format = "PNG")
logo <- png::readPNG("logo/combinedlogo.png")
```

You should now be able to access `logo` as a 3-d array.

Unfortunately I can't make this reproducible without the original files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That helps resolving my question!